# How do I rename uploaded files?

Tags: 7, files

How do I rename the uploaded files for my module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find some information about how to code changing file names in the [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = file_save_upload('file' , array(
  'file_validate_is_image' => array(), 
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg docx')
),'',FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$file->filename = basename($file->uri);
if ($file) {
  if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://rohit')) {
    $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer could use some more info, such as _where_ this code goes.

Comment: It seems the code should go into HOOK_background_form_validate(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903458/drupal-7-rename-files-on-upload-via-filefield for details